# Google search from Python program

Tags: python, google-search

I'm trying to take an input file, read each line, search google with that line and print all the search results from the query ONLY IF the result is from a specific website. A simple example to illustrate my point, if I search dog I only want results printed from wikipedia, whether that be one result or ten results from wikipedia. My problem is I've been getting really weird results. Below is my Python code which contains a specific URL I want results from.

My program

```
inputFile = open("small.txt", 'r') # Makes File object
outputFile = open("results1.txt", "w") 
dictionary = {}  # Our "hash table"
compare = "www.someurl.com/" # urls will compare against this string

from googlesearch import GoogleSearch

for line in inputFile.read().splitlines():
    lineToRead = line
    dictionary[lineToRead] = [] #initialzed to empty list
    gs = GoogleSearch(lineToRead)
    for url in gs.top_urls():
        print url # check to make sure this is printing URLs
        compare2 = url
        if compare in compare2: #compare the two URLs, if they match 
            dictionary[lineToRead].append(url) #write out query string to dictionary key & append EACH url that matches 
inputFile.close()

for i in dictionary:
    print i # this print is a test that shows what the query was in google (dictionary key)
    outputFile.write(i+"\n")
    for j in dictionary[i]: 
        print j # this print is a test that shows the results from the query which should look like correct URL: "www.medicaldepartmentstore.com/..."(dictionary value(s))
        outputFile.write(j+"\n") #write results for the query string to the output file.
```

My output file is incorrect, the way it's supposed to be formatted is

```
query string
http://www.
http://www.
http://www.
query string
http://www.
query string
http://www.medical...
http://www.medical...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you limit the scope of the results to the specific site (e.g. wikipedia) at the time of the query? For example, using:

```
gs = GoogleSearch("site:wikipedia.com %s" % query) #as shown in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlesearch/0.7.0
```

This would instruct Google to return only the results from that domain, so you won't need to filter them after seeing the results.

Comment: If you care about having results from more than one domain, you can write a little method to generate the `site` string. To do multiple sites, just use `OR` - like `site:wikipedia.org OR site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I didn't think of that but that's exactly what I want to do. @Cahit

Comment: @Tommy, thats a great suggestion for a different problem but I was hoping to limit my results to just one specific domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Cahit has the right idea. The only reason you would be getting lines of *just the query string* is because the domain you were looking for wasn't in the `top_urls()`. You can verify this by checking if the array contained in the dictionary for a given key is empty

```
for i in dictionary:
    outputFile.write("%s: " % str(i))
    if len(dictionary[i]) == 0:
        outputFile.write("No results in top_urls\n")
    else:
        outputFile.write("%s\n" % ", ".join(dictionary[i]))
```